# IOS Simulator Color does not match storyboard / original images

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.1

When I run my app within the simulator, the color of the images that I put in does match what the image looks like.   I tried different color profiles within photoshop, tried not converting to sRGB, tried png/jpg/etc..  to no avail.  I did find one post on here that recommends taking a screen shot and then adjusting the original rgb values within photoshop, but that seems like a hack to me.  Is there any way to output a PNG from photoshop and have it look the same on the simulator (or real device)?  Here's a screenshot that shows the image in the storyboard (left) and the simulator (right): https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Llk6.png  ...  I'm running XCode 6.1.1